# OOP Battleship implementation in Java - part 2

Tags: java, object-oriented

Previous review can be found **[here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161680/oop-battleship-console-game-in-java/161695#161695)**

I got so many great tips on how to improve, so I've written a new version while trying to implement all the different suggestions.

So once again, any insight with regards to clean code, best practices etc. would be greatly appreciated.

**Board.java**

```
package com.tn.board;

import com.tn.field.IGameField;
import com.tn.field.WaterField;
import com.tn.ship.Ship;
import com.tn.field.ShipField;
import com.tn.ship.ShipSize;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Board {
    private static final char WATER = '~';
    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 10;
    private static final char[] BOARD_LETTERS = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};
    private static final String HORIZONTAL = "H";
    private static final String VERTICAL = "V";

    private Scanner scanner;
    private IGameField[][] board;
    private static final Ship[] ships;

    static {
        ships = new Ship[] {
                new Ship("Carrier", ShipSize.CARRIER),
                new Ship("Battleship", ShipSize.BATTLESHIP),
                new Ship("Cruiser", ShipSize.CRUISER),
                new Ship("Submarine", ShipSize.SUBMARINE),
                new Ship("Destroyer", ShipSize.DESTROYER)
        };
    }

    public Board() {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.board = new IGameField[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                board[i][j] = new WaterField();
            }
        }

    }

    public void placeShipsOnBoard() {
        for(Ship ship : ships) {
            boolean horizontal = askValidShipDirection();
            Point startingPoint = askValidStartingPoint(ship, horizontal);
            placeValidShip(ship, startingPoint, horizontal);

            printBoard();
        }
    }

    public IGameField getField(int x, int y) {
        if(!isInsideBoard(x, y)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Outside board - try again: ");
        }
        return board[y][x];
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        System.out.print("\t");

        for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.print(BOARD_LETTERS[i] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.print((i+1) + "\t");
            for(int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j].getIcon() + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private boolean askValidShipDirection() {
        System.out.printf("%nDo you want to place the ship horizontally (H) or vertically (V)?");
        String direction;
        do {
            direction = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        }while (!HORIZONTAL.equals(direction) && !VERTICAL.equals(direction));

        return HORIZONTAL.equals(direction);
    }

    private Point askValidStartingPoint(Ship ship, boolean horizontal) {
        Point from;
        do {
            System.out.printf("%nEnter position of %s (length  %d): ", ship.getName(), ship.getSize());
            from = new Point(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
        } while(!isValidStartingPoint(from, ship.getSize(), horizontal));

        return from;
    }

    private boolean isValidStartingPoint(Point from, int length, boolean horizontal) {
        int xDiff = 0;
        int yDiff = 0;
        if(horizontal) {
            xDiff = 1;
        } else {
            yDiff = 1;
        }

        int x = (int)from.getX() - 1;
        int y = (int)from.getY() - 1;
        if(!isInsideBoard(x, y) ||
                (!isInsideBoard(x + length,y) && horizontal) ||
                (!isInsideBoard(x, y + length) && !horizontal)
                ) {
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(board[(int)from.getY() + i *yDiff - 1]
                    [(int)from.getX() + i *xDiff - 1].getIcon() != WATER){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void placeValidShip(Ship ship, Point startingPoint, boolean horizontal) {
        int xDiff = 0;
        int yDiff = 0;
        if(horizontal) {
            xDiff = 1;
        } else {
            yDiff = 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < ship.getSize() ; i++) {
            board[(int)startingPoint.getY() + i*yDiff - 1]
                    [(int)startingPoint.getX()+ i*xDiff - 1] = new ShipField(ship);
        }
    }
    private boolean isInsideBoard(int x, int y){
        return x <= BOARD_SIZE && x >= 0
                && y <= BOARD_SIZE && y >= 0;
    }
}
```

**IGameField.java**

```
package com.tn.field;

import com.tn.game.Result;


public interface IGameField {
    char getIcon();
    Result shootAt();
}
```

**ShipField.java**

```
package com.tn.field;

import com.tn.game.Result;
import com.tn.ship.Ship;


public class ShipField implements IGameField {
    private final Ship ship;

    public ShipField(Ship ship) {
        this.ship = ship;
    }

    @Override
    public char getIcon() {
        char icon;
        Result shipState = ship.getState();
        switch (shipState) {
            case PARTIAL_HIT: icon = 'O';
                break;
            case DESTROYED: icon = 'O';
                break;
            case NO_HIT: icon = 'X';
                break;
            default: icon = ' ';
                break;
        }
        return icon;
    }

    @Override
    public Result shootAt() {
        ship.hit();
        return ship.getState();
    }
}
```

**WaterField.java**

```
package com.tn.field;

import com.tn.game.Result;


public class WaterField implements IGameField {
    private boolean isThisFieldHit = false;

    @Override
    public char getIcon() {
        return isThisFieldHit ? 'M' : '~';
    }

    @Override
    public Result shootAt() {
        isThisFieldHit = true;
        return Result.NO_HIT;
    }
}
```

**IPlayer.java**

```
package com.tn.player;


public interface IPlayer {
    void placeShips();
    void fireAt(IPlayer opponent);
    int getTotalLivesLeft();
}
```

**HumanPlayer.java**

```
package com.tn.player;

import com.tn.board.Board;
import com.tn.game.Result;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HumanPlayer implements IPlayer {
    private int totalLivesLeft = 17;

    private int id;
    private Board board;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public HumanPlayer(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.board = new Board();
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    @Override
    public void placeShips() {
        System.out.printf("%n======== Player %d - Time to place out your ships ========%n", id);
        board.placeShipsOnBoard();
    }

    @Override
    public void fireAt(IPlayer opponent) {
        System.out.printf("%n Alright Player %d - Enter coordinates for your attack: ", id);

        boolean isPointValid = false;
        while(!isPointValid) {
            try {
                Point point = new Point(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
                int x = (int)point.getX() - 1;
                int y = (int)point.getY() - 1;

                Result result = ((HumanPlayer)opponent)
                        .getBoard()
                        .getField(x, y)
                        .shootAt();

                if(result == Result.PARTIAL_HIT ||  result == Result.DESTROYED) {
                    totalLivesLeft--;
                }

                isPointValid = true;
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.printf(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getTotalLivesLeft() {
        return totalLivesLeft;
    }


}
```

**Ship.java**

```
package com.tn.ship;

import com.tn.game.Result;


public class Ship {
    private final String name;
    private final int size;
    private int lives;

    public Ship(String name, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.lives = size;
    }

    public void hit() {
        if(lives > 0) {
            System.out.printf("%nGood shot! The %s was hit", name);
            lives--;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ship is destroyed");
        }
    }

    public Result getState() {
        if(lives == 0) {
            return Result.DESTROYED;
        } else if(lives < size) {
            return Result.PARTIAL_HIT;
        } else {
            return Result.NO_HIT;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

**ShipSize.java**

```
package com.tn.ship;


public class ShipSize {
    private ShipSize() {
    }

    public static final int CARRIER = 5;
    public static final int BATTLESHIP = 4;
    public static final int CRUISER = 3;
    public static final int SUBMARINE = 3;
    public static final int DESTROYER = 2;
}
```

**Result.java**

```
package com.tn.game;


public enum Result {
    NO_HIT,
    PARTIAL_HIT,
    DESTROYED
}
```

**Game.java**

```
package com.tn.game;

import com.tn.player.HumanPlayer;


public class Game {
    private HumanPlayer[] players;

    public Game() {

        this.players = new HumanPlayer[]{
                new HumanPlayer(1),
                new HumanPlayer(2)
        };
    }

    public void start() {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        int len = players.length;
        HumanPlayer player = null;

        this.players[i].placeShips();
        this.players[j].placeShips();

        while(players[0].getTotalLivesLeft() > 0 &&
                players[1].getTotalLivesLeft() > 0) {

            players[i++ % len].fireAt(players[j++ % len]);
            player = (players[0].getTotalLivesLeft() < players[1].getTotalLivesLeft()) ?
                    players[1] :
                    players[0];
        }

        System.out.printf("Congrats Player %d, you won!",player.getId());
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import com.tn.game.Game;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to make `public static` constants use `interface`.

   ```
   public interface Constants {
       final String SIZE = 5;
   }
   ```
2. What is the purpose of the `Board` class? It seems like a global controller for the whole game process. Those validations strive to be moved into some validator class (`CollisionValidator` or `CollisionManager` is the common class in the most games). I mean your `Board` class is doing drawing, validation and storing game-world objects at once. Pretty big and difficult to extend class.
3. `ShipSize` is a redundant class (not to say it should be an enum). You use its values only in one place - at the static initializer. You can either move ships names and their sizes to some sort of `Ships` enum or use integers constants directly at your static initializer.

   ```
   public enum Ships {
       CARRIER("Carrier", 5),
       BATTLESHIP("Battleship", 4),
       CRUISER("Cruiser", 3),
       SUBMARINE("Submarine", 3),
       DESTROYER("Destroyer", 2);

       private String name;
       private int size;

       Ships(String name, int size) {
           this.name = name;
           this.size = size;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Also every model you have can draw, which neglects separation of concerns. It can be hard to debug such things and can become pretty complicated. Always is a good idea to create a printer class which only can use `System.out.print`, where all methods take entities with their values to print (entities ideally should not say how to print themselves).

Comment: Enum was a great suggestions, I have changed to that now. I agree that the board class i big, but everything inside that class is board-related. So I'm a little unclear as to how I should split that up. I will also try to implement a printer class. If you could demonstrate some of the things you said with code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't like this review for two reasons: 1: the first point isn't justified at all. Extracting all constants into a `Constants` interface is IMO a **really** bad idea, because it breaks the separation of concerns and using an interface for that task is problematic because interfaces have no means of instance-control.
And 2. The (correct) advice to separate out printing entities from these entities is given as an absolute (which is usually incorrect to do) and it's not justified. Other than that: Welcome to Code Review :)

Comment: 1. I suggested to use interface because it has a default `public static` which he was using in `ShipSize` class. Why does he need to use a class for that?
2. I have no clue why it can be incorrect, but I encountered the same problem when view output was splitted among all project and it was quite a challenge to extend it. So even in small games I am trying to follow this rule. Maybe it's my own mistake.